# Throws exception in online complier but works fine in IDE

Tags: java, swing

While performing this simple Java GUI code in Eclipse IDE it works fine

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class SimpleGui {
public static void main(String[] args) {
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JButton button = new JButton("Click me!");

frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.getContentPane().add(button);
frame.setSize(200, 200);
frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

and produces a result like this image.

[image: Output]

But while trying out the same program in the online GDB compiler it throws the following error. I ensured that the class name and file name are the same (`Main.java`) in the online compiler.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':1' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:115)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:103)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:82)
    at java.awt.Window.initGC(Window.java:475)
    at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:495)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:537)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:189)
    at Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

What is the reason behind this error and how could it be resolved?

Comment: Why do you think an online compiler can show you swing components?

Comment: How do you expect an online compiler to show a non-online GUI like awt/swing to you?

Comment: The reason is in the exception message _"Can't connect to X11 window server using ':1' as the value of the DISPLAY variable."_. In other words, that online IDE can't show GUI components.

Comment: Never heard of this tool, but if it's referring to onlinegdb.com (http://question.onlinegdb.com), it's internal question/answer engine does appear to have answered mentions of using AWT, so maybe it does support it, at least on some platforms? Check to see if that feature set is support on your platform, Krithick.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs! But wondering why it isn't possible for online compilers to show swing components?